# removing unwanted charactors from a file-Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm reading a text file and extract two columns spliting by space and writing them in to another text file. There are '-' charactors in some of the lines. I want to remove them and write. Whats wrong with the following code?I have used line.replace() also which didn't work.

```
fo = open('referrer.txt','rw')

try:
  for line in open('c1'):

      if line.startswith('#'):
          continue
      else:
          resource = line.split(' ')[5]
          fo.write(re.sub('-',' ',line.split(' ')[11]) +' '+resource + '\n')
except: 
  pass
fo.close()
```

more info : c1 is having lot of information in each line separated by a space. I'm reading it extract 5th and 11th strings in each line. then this referrer.txt line has some thing like "abssfdf-cfgd abc". I want to remove the '-' character in each line before writin it to referrer.txt?

Comment: you should try some print debug statements

Comment: You're not giving enough information for us to help you... What error do you get? What kind of inputs do you give to your code? All I can tell you there, is that your sub is fine, I'm sure the replace would be too. I think your problem may be in how you handle the line split.

Comment: Depending on how big the file is:  `new_file.write(old_file.read().replace('-',''))` might work

Comment: @zmo c1 is having lot of information in each line separated by a space. I'm reading it extract 5th and 11th strings in each line. then this referrer.txt line has some thing like "abssfdf-cfgd abc". I want to remove the '-' character in each line?

Comment: You probably don't want catch all exceptions using `except`. This will hide other problems in your code. Determine which exceptions can occur and just catch those. It might also be helpful to display some error when an exception occurs.

Answer (score 2):

When you write, it moves pointer of the file forward and override original contents. The following reading is begin at where your writing ends.

You'd better write to a new file.

Comment: it doesn't seem like he is writing in the same file.

Comment: @njzk2 I'm a she..:) I'm writing it to the same file

Comment: You can simply write to a new file. Finally, rename the new file to override the original one.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage : sorry about that. i usually say 'they' when in doubts. i thought `open('c1')` would not open the same file as `open('referrer.txt','rw')` ?

Comment: @Sherwood Wang Thanks It suits for me

Comment: @njzk Sorry, I misunderstood, c1 and referrer.txt are two files, I said I want to write the '-' removed lines to the referrer.txt?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Sorry, I didn't notice they are two different files... The 5th string is at line.split(' ')[4]. And you'd better not ignore all exceptions. Perhaps there is IO exception.

Answer (score -1):

if you are under linux use Sed command !

```
import commands
commands.getstatusoutput('sed -i 's/\-/ /g' /youfile.txt')
```

to ignore the line starting with '#' use :
    **grep -v "#" file.txt > other_filer.txt**.
I used to use OS commands to handle files.